# Access Stage variables - AWS API Gateway

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have Stage variables defined under **AWS API GATEWAY**.

I want to access the values, that I have defined for these, in the request handler written in Scala.
According to the AWS API gateway console, Stage variables can be accessed using the **$context** object.

[image: Stage variables through context]

The documentation of the context object is present [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-context-object.html) but it does not define how to use the stage variables in the handleRequest method.

```
override def handleRequest(input: java.util.Map[java.lang.String, Object], context: Context): util.Map[String, _] = {
    context.getLogger.log("Input: " + input + " \n")
    // How do I access the Stage variable here?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the contents of `context` object ?

Comment: @Can How do I do that? I am relatively new to Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use body mapping template in the integration request section and create a JSON like the sample below to get stage variable.

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
"version" : "$stageVariables.version"
}
```

Source :- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/amazon-api-gateway-using-stage-variables.html#call-api-lambda-backend-with-stage-variable

If you are sure about body mapping template please have a look on https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tag/mapping-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Vijayanath's answer is a simple way to achieve what is required.

If you want to do it in a programmatically way and without the need to change the `stageVariables` from the console, 
then I would suggest using **Swagger API** integration to handle the stage variables.

You can achieve this using the json templates as defined here - [AWS labs Swagger Api](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer) and by adding the below lines under `x-amazon-apigateway-integration`

```
"requestTemplates": {
    "application/json": "#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')) \n{ \n \"version\" : \"$stageVariables.version\" \n}"
    }
```

So the entire json file would be:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-auth" : {

    "type" : "aws_iam"
},
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
   "type" : "aws",
   "uri" : "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:MY_ACCT_ID:function:helloWorld/invocations",
   "httpMethod" : "POST",
   "credentials" : "arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCT_ID:role/lambda_exec_role",
   "requestTemplates": {
"application/json": "#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')) \n{ \n \"version\" : \"$stageVariables.version\" \n}"
},
   "requestParameters" : {
       "integration.request.path.integrationPathParam" :     "method.request.querystring.latitude",
       "integration.request.querystring.integrationQueryParam" :     "method.request.querystring.longitude"
   },
   "cacheNamespace" : "cache-namespace",
   "cacheKeyParameters" : [],
   "responses" : {
       "2\\d{2}" : {
           "statusCode" : "200",
           "responseParameters" : {
               "method.response.header.test-method-response-header" :     "integration.response.header.integrationResponseHeaderParam1"
           },
           "responseTemplates" : {
               "application/json" : "json 200 response template",
               "application/xml" : "xml 200 response template"
           }
       },
       "default" : {
           "statusCode" : "400",
           "responseParameters" : {
               "method.response.header.test-method-response-header" : "'static value'"
           },
           "responseTemplates" : {
               "application/json" : "json 400 response template",
               "application/xml" : "xml 400 response template"
           }
       }
   }
}
```